# What is the difference between bindCallback and bindNodeCallback in RxJs API?

Tags: rxjs

I want to know what is the difference between bindCallback and bindNodeCallback methods, in [RxJs API](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html); and how to know when use one or another.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that Node callbacks always take an error as the first parameter. From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) for `bindNodeCallback`:

> The callback function is expected to follow Node.js conventions, where the first argument to the callback is an error, while remaining arguments are the callback result.

RxJS will take this into account and will wire up the callback's `error` parameter to the observable's error notification mechanism. That's not possible with `bindCallback`, as there is no convention for the parameters.